# rational functions on projective n space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

> How to prove that the field of rational functions on whole of projective $n$-space is constant functions?

By rational function I mean quotients of homogeneous polynomials of same degree defined/regular on whole of projective space.

Comment: Do you mean regular functions? The field of rational functions on the projective n-space consists of any quotient of homogeneous polynomial of $(n+1)$ variables of the same degree.

Comment: I meant  the field of rational functions on the projective n-space, which consists of any quotient of homogeneous polynomial of (n+1) variables of the same degree, but they should be defined on any point of projective space, i.e there should be one representation for which the denominator does not vanish at a point in the projective space, and that should be true for all points.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A rational function $\phi\in \text {Rat}(\mathbb P^n)$ is defined at $p\in \mathbb P^n$ if there is some representative $P/Q$ of $\phi$ with $P,Q\in k[T_0,\cdots,T_n]$ homogeneous of the same degree such that $Q(p)\neq 0$.
You are asking to characterize those $\phi$'s that are defined at all $p\in  \mathbb P^n$.
The answer is that the only such $\phi$ are the elements of $k$, the constants . Here is why:

Any non-constant $\phi\in \text {Rat}(\mathbb P^n)$ has a *unique* (up to a non-zero constant ) expression of  the form  $P/Q$ with $P,Q$ homogeneous of the same positive degree and, crucially!, with $P,Q$ relatively prime.
The reason for this pleasant unicity is of course that $k[T_0,\cdots,T_n]$ is a UFD when $k$ is a field.
But now I claim that at any zero $p\in \mathbb P^n$ of $Q$, the rational function $\phi$ is *not* defined.
**Proof of claim**
Another representative of $\phi$ will be of the form  $P_1/Q_1$ with $P_1,Q_1$ homogeneous of the same degree .
Since $P/Q,P_1/Q_1$ both represent $\phi$, we have $PQ_1=P_1Q$  so that $Q$ divides $PQ_1$ and since $P,Q$ are relatively prime $Q$ must divide $Q_1$.
Ah, but then $Q(p)=0$ implies $Q_1(p)=0$: so try as we can we will never find a representative of $\phi$ whose denominator does not vanish at $p$.
Long story short, $\phi$ is not defined at $p$.

The end of the story is that if we assume $k$ algebraically closed, any homogeneous polynomial of positive degree $Q$ will have some zero $p$ and the reasoning above shows that no non-constant $\phi\in \text {Rat}(\mathbb P^n)\setminus k$ is defined on all of $\mathbb P^n$.

**Say it in formulas**
$$  \mathcal O(\mathbb P^n)=k\subsetneq     \text {Rat}(\mathbb P^n)=k(T_1/T_0,\cdots, T_n/T_0)\subsetneq   k(T_0,T_1,\cdots, T_n) =   \text {Rat}(\mathbb P^n)(T_0)    $$

Comment: Great answer, and great writing style. Very nice.

Comment: I'm glad you liked  the answer, user 4567.