# Global functions of a projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field. How can I find a proper proof for
$$ \bigcap_{i=0}^{n}K[\frac{X_0}{X_i},...,\frac{X_n}{ X_i}]=K.$$

I need the above in order to prove that the global functions on projective space are constant functions.

Comment: You need the polynomial rings $K[\frac{X_0}{X_i},\cdots,\frac{X_n}{X_i}]$, as the fields $K(\frac{X_0}{X_i},\cdots,\frac{X_n}{X_i})$ are all equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rational functions on projective n space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386679/rational-functions-on-projective-n-space)